# Warning 4244 (possible loss of data) in template class - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: templates, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

i do have a little problem, I would like to solve.

Using a class template, i check the data type with typeid() to handle them in the right manner.

---

```
  template <typename _Ty_Id,
            typename _Ty_Value>
  class Attribute : public AttributeBase<_Ty_Id>
  {
    public: 
      Attribute() : 
        AttributeBase(_Ty_Id()),
        m_tyValue(_Ty_Value())
      {
      }

      Attribute(_Ty_Id tyId, _Ty_Value tyValue) : 
        AttributeBase(tyId),
        m_tyValue(tyValue)
      {
      }

      virtual ~Attribute() {};

      virtual  _Ty_Id    getId()    const {return m_tyId;}
      virtual  _Ty_Value getValue() const {return m_tyValue;}

      virtual void toXml(iolib::Xml& xmlFile)
      {
        std::list<std::string> listXmlData;
        std::string strTag;

        if(typeid(m_tyId) == typeid(std::string))
        {
          strTag = m_tyId;
        }
        else
        {
          strTag = core::Stringfunc::format(strTag, m_tyId, 0, 0);
        }

        listXmlData.push_back(strTag);
        listXmlData.push_back("entrytype");
        listXmlData.push_back(m_strEntryType);
        listXmlData.push_back("datatype");
        listXmlData.push_back(m_strDataType);

        std::string strValue;
        if(typeid(m_tyValue) == typeid(std::string))
        {
          #pragma warning(disable : 4244)
          strValue = m_tyValue;
          #pragma warning(default : 4244)
        }
        else if((typeid(m_tyValue) == typeid(float)) || 
                (typeid(m_tyValue) == typeid(double)))
        {
          strValue = core::Stringfunc::format(strValue, m_tyValue, 0, 3);
        }
        else
        {
          strValue = core::Stringfunc::format(strValue, m_tyValue, 0, 0);
        }

        listXmlData.push_back(strValue);
        listXmlData.push_back("/" + strTag);

        xmlFile.addElement(listXmlData);
      }


    private:
      _Ty_Value m_tyValue;
  }
```

---

The template argument is a float value and will be handled in the else if branch. But, VS 2010 will bring warning #4244, that an implicit cast from float to std::string might not work correctly.

So far, I disabled that warning just there where it happens, and everything will be fine. But, that will of course only work with VS2012 and want to use my code with different targets.

Does anyone knows a smarter way to prevent the warning?

---

EDIT

So, now I did post a major part of the class.

The problem is within the method: toXml(iolib::Xml& xmlFile), with will accept a referenct to my xml class. The used type (m_tyValue) is a member of the Attribute<> class.

The template arguments are: std::string for m_tyId and float for m_tyValue.

Best regards,
Coast

Comment: Don't make use of RTTI... It should be avoided whereever possible. What is your aim?

Comment: Well... I thought using RTTI for checking the type is a nice way. I would like to write a value to a xml file. Therefore it need to be a string in any case. When the template argument is float or integer type, I use a format method to do the job. Maybe that should also handle strings (and do nothing in that case?)

Comment: Well, I am not a 100% sure about this, but relying on this is never a good way. It can become very obscure. I don't want to you to give it up, but for sake of functionality, why don't you ry your Suggestion? Maybe it appears it is better!?

Comment: Please show us more code. It looks to me like this is not a good way to deal with different template type arguments (best would be a SSCCE).

Comment: You mean try? ("why don't you ry your Suggestion?"

Comment: sorry... what is a SSCE? First time here XD

Comment: Typo, I meant SSCCE, short self-contained correct/compiling example. A short, complete example, it is.

Comment: not easy to do, as it heavily depends on my framework. But, I will try. Not sure, how much code I can post here? Is there a way to handle attachments?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to see the function definition (parameters etc.) and how you call it.

Comment: added some code to my post. Hope it will help :)

Comment: Yes I think it does. What type is `m_tyId`?

Comment: m_tyId is a string, therefore no warning appears. m_tyValue is a float.

Comment: You might want to use `#pragma warning(push)` and `pop` next time, to ensure the state is reset correctly (it might have not been `default` in the beginning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: you should not use names beginning with `__` (double underscore) or with `_` and an uppercase letter. Those are reserved "for the implementation" [global.names] in the C++ Std

To get different behaviour for different types (where you know the type at compile time), you use can use (partial) specialization of the class template:

```
template < typename Ty_Id >
struct toXmlHelper
{}; // provide no default implementation

template < >
struct toXmlHelper < double > // implementation in case Ty_Id == double
{
    void toXml() { /*...*/ }
};

template < >
struct toXmlHelper < std::string > // implementation in case Ty_Id == std::string
{
    void toXml() { /*...*/ }
};
```

You might want to add techniques to reduce code redundancy.

Another way would be to use the overloading mechanism:

```
template < typename Ty_Id,
           typename Ty_Value>
class Attribute : public AttributeBase<_Ty_Id>
{
public:
    /* ... */
    virtual void toXml(iolib::Xml& xmlFile)
    {
        std::list<std::string> listXmlData;
        std::string strTag;
        /* ... */
        toXmlHelper(m_tyId);
    }
private:
    void toXmlHelper(double);
    void toXmlHelper(std::string const&);
}
```

As you know the type of `m_tyId`, there's no reason to use *Run-Time Type Info*. The warning appears as the code (in each if-clase) in compiled for all instantiations of your class template, even if it does not make sense, like assigning a float to a string.

Comment: Yes, partial specialization... did not think about that. Thank you for the sample I will try it, it's looking good. Will let you know if it's working. So far, thank's alot :)